# How do I make plugin pages work with Timber?

Tags: timber

I'm converting an existing site to use Timber. Here's what I've done so far:

- Installed Timber.
- Manually installed the Timber Starter Theme and copied over some custom functions from the old theme.

The issue is that page templates from plugins don't seem to be working at all. Specifically, the calendar page from The Events Calendar and the built in templates from Elementor (Elementor Full Width and Elementor Canvas). All I get is a completely blank screen. Here's the [calendar page](https://refactor-valor-christian.pantheonsite.io/calendar/). 
I thought this would work automatically because of the functions in `header.php` and `footer.php`. Is there something else I need to do to get plugin pages to display?

Answer (score 1):

There's an article on a method to integrate The Events Calendar with Timber here:

https://theeventscalendar.com/support/forums/topic/events-pages-not-showing-up-in-timber-based-theme/

I've used this myself and it works well, one caveat however is that in more recent version of TEC you need to make sure **Use updated calendar designs** is **not** selected otherwise there is a mismatch between the enqueued CSS and the rendered views.

Comment: Thanks Antony. I posted this issue on github as well and the plugin author (Jared) wasn't able to replicate it. Then I tried it again on a different site and couldn't replicate it either. Here's the thread for reference: https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/2273#issuecomment-656221131
But according to the thread you posted it's a documented issue, so I'm not sure what to make of this. Seems like it's hit or miss whether it'll be an issue on any particular site. Anyway thanks for sharing that. I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: FYI that method above I sent is no longer required. Fixing this was driving me mental for a while but I managed to track it down to the page-template.twig file missing....